# How to access multiple attributes at the same instance using mbeans?

Tags: jakarta-mail, mbeans

I have javamail program which gets size of each mail in my gmail inbox. I am accessing size using mbeans in a client program. how do i get to know which mail's size it is showing in the client program?

I need to get **more than 1 value in the client program at the same instance**,i.e. the mail size and the mail number. What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question.  What do you mean **which** mail size?  Do you mean "the size for which message"?  However you're communicating the size to the client program, you're also going to have to communicate something about the message, such as its message number.  More details about what you're doing might help us provide a better answer.